# Methods to show audience specific content

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, geotargeting, profiling

I'm trying to find out what methods there are for showing specific content to my website visitors based on profiles, the criteria include: country, language, age, gender.

It's reliable enough for me to base the country information on the visitors IP but i'd like to tailor my content more to my visitors preferences.

Ideally i'd hope that there is some way to get this information for each session from Google Analytics and then choose what content to load but i don't see how to do that based on the current visitor.

I hope some of you can point me in the right direction.
(programming experience will not be an issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is impossible, but unfortunately the reply to your question is that is very hard.

If you want to take data from Analytics you'll have some problems:

1. Analytics doesn't update the live results that matter to you such as Age and Gender, which means some time is needed to have data for that categories;
2. Not even Google can know 100% of the profile of the user that is showing your page, so the results you see are approximate. It's ok for logged in google users but the others are matched by behavior approximation, which is never 100% true.

If you want my opinion, the best way is to get the country by IP and the Browser Language to adapt the content. Age & Gender can be interesting to analyse and adapt your future content to go more towards Men / Women or Male / Female.